Is the order of the Torah part of the principles of faith?
According to my understanding of Rambam's 8th of his 13 principles of faith it is necessary to believe that the Torah as we currently have it is exactly what was told to Moshe by God. From what I gather this principle is focused on substance; what is in the Torah today is word for word what God told Moshe.
However, I am unsure if this extends to the order of the material as well. Does the 8th principle mandate belief that every chapter and verse are in the same order today as when God said them to Moshe?

If we can rearrange things, we could anagram the Torah to say whatever we wanted.

@DoubleAA the question is about belief not permission to edit

Even if not, surely the order is covered by the 9th principle?

@RabbiKaii how so? Rearranging does not add or detract

@RabbiKaii Do you think it's plausible that a Jew believing in Judaism would believe the Torah text was originally arranged to produce the Gospels and then later was rearranged into the current order?

@DoubleAA I don't follow sorry? Is it the "even if not"? I actually basically agree with your comment about the 8th as ruling out this position, and gave it an upvote (but the question is limiting the reordering to chapter and verse only, so anagram/gospel is inapplicable) I am only lightly looking into this and considering that the 9th principle means the Torah will never be changed. Changing the order would seem to be covered by that, but I could be wrong. It might be more specific. Riki - rearranging could certainly add or detract from the meaning (we aren't talking about quantity), right?

@RabbiKaii sorry meant to tag @ rikitiki. Incidentally I don't see the difference between rearranging chapters and rearranging letters

@DoubleAA Countdown would be a very different game if there were verse tiles rather than letters

You mean, the Torah could possibly be saying, "Hear, O Lord, Israel is our god"?

Rearranging does add and detract because we learn many lessons from the order things are presented in the Torah, therefore we must believe that the order is the same as that of Moshe Rabbeinu.
